# how to split a single column data into muliple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
# import Pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# create a new data frame 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['1234567 A: John Larter 123456  451151515 A: Robert Junior 4646466 9865513 A: Jonny Depp 9456561'], 
                  }) 
df
```

All the data is piled up on single column. I need to get data after each  A: in sepearte column

Expected DataFrame

```
# import Pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# create a new data frame 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A: John Larter 123456', 'A: Robert Junior 4646466', 'A: Jonny Depp 9456561'], 
                  }) 
df
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `Series.str.split()` and choose a splitting pattern that fits your needs. For example:

```py
print(df.Name.str.split(r"\d+\sA:\s", expand = True).T)

                        0
0                        
1    John Larter 123456  
2  Robert Junior 4646466 
3      Jonny Depp 9456561
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Series.str.extract` to extract your pattern in the column:

```
d = df['Name'].str.extractall('(A:\s[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+\s\d+)').to_numpy()
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Name'])

                       Name
0     A: John Larter 123456
1  A: Robert Junior 4646466
2     A: Jonny Depp 9456561
```

Answer (score 1):

Borrow Erfan's `regex` use `explode` with `findall`

```
df['Name'].str.findall('(A:\s[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+\s\d+)').explode()
0       A: John Larter 123456
0    A: Robert Junior 4646466
0       A: Jonny Depp 9456561
Name: Name, dtype: object
```